# Rounding up and down a number C++

Tags: c++, cmath, ceil

I'm trying to allow my program to round a number up and down respectively.

For example, if the number is `3.6`, my program is suppose to round up the nearest number which is 4 and if the number is `3.4`, it will be rounded down to 3.

I tried using the `ceil` library to get the average of 3 items.

`results = ceil((marks1 + marks2 + marks3)/3)`

However, the `ceil` only rounds the number down but does not roll the number up.

There's 1 algorithm i stumbled upon

`var roundedVal = Math.round(origVal*20)/20;`

but i still can't figure a formula for some problem.

Comment: You are not rounding both up and down. You are just rounding.

Comment: What is `Math.round()` ? is it C++ or Java?

Comment: "However, the `ceil` only rounds the number down..." Surely, you mean `ceil` only rounds up?

Comment: What is `var`? What is `Math.round`?

Comment: @R_Kapp i tried it but it seems to round down when i tried something like that `(ceil(1 + 3 + 6)/3)`

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan: That's integer math. `(1 + 3 + 6) / 3` is going to return exactly `3` (because all numbers are integers), and `ceil`, `floor` and `round` of `3` will be `3`. Try `(1.0 + 3.0 + 6.0) / 3.0` instead.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre dude calm down. It seems that it is from JavaScript. No need to bash the OP though.

Comment: @leaf you're right, I should be in a good mood right now. Think that the guy has 3k rep, should ask better questions.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Oh man, your right, he does have 3k rep. I do agree, that his question should be much better, but lets tell him that in a way that keeps everybody in a good mood ;)

Comment: @ChristianDean I wish you would comment under my questions too haha

Comment: @DavidTóth Haha thanks. I try to keep the peace when I can.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
std::ceil
```

rounds up to the nearest integer

```
std::floor
```

rounds down to the nearest integer

```
std::round
```

performs the behavior you expect

please give a use case with numbers if this does not provide you with what you need!

Comment: @Teo Chuen Wei Bryan (ceil(1 + 3 + 6)/3) should be ceil((1 + 3 + 6)/3.0)

Comment: it should be noted that we are talking here about [<cmath>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath) since we are using C++ and it's important.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need a function to round in C or C++. You can just use a simple trick. Add 0.5 and then cast to an integer. That's probably all round does anyway.

```
double d = 3.1415;
double d2 = 4.7;
int i1 = (int)(d + 0.5);
int i2 = (int)(d2 + 0.5);
```

i1 is 3, and i2 is 5. You can verify it yourself.

Comment: Nice to know, but I prefer functions

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt wherever it is possible (unless it seriously hurts readability of code) it is best to avoid functions, as they imply a lot of overhead

Comment: @GregorWattersHärtl That's not true at all. They do not implay a "lot" of overhead.

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt that depends on your interpretation of "a lot". The same bit of code executed outside a function will have less overhead than the same code executed inside a function that is called (as long as the function has not been inlined), hence my suggestion to avoid function calls, where possible (especially inside loops).

Comment: @GregorWattersHärtl I'm pretty sure that in pretty much any production C++ application, performance degradation due to function calls is irrelevant. Unless you are implementing a library that needs to be highly performant, [readability should take precedence over performance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/89620/clean-readable-code-vs-fast-hard-to-read-code-when-to-cross-the-line). Performance loss usually takes place in a different way.

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt there, I totally agree with you. Personally, I also prefer having my code look organised (using function calls), rather than just inlining the code, even though it might cost me a few fractions of a second :P

Comment: @GregorHartlWatters The compiler will inline such small functions anyway. Better to keep your code clean with using functions and let the compiler inline them.

Comment: To help the compiler inline them (without linker support) the functions can be put into headers. E.g. by declaring them inline, static (not the static inside class/struct, but the static that the function is valid for the current translation unit only), as template or putting them into a class definition. Otherwise you have to rely on whole program optimization / link time optimization or whatever the feature is called for your compiler.

Answer (score 9):

The function you need is called [round](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/), believe it or not.

`ceil` rounds UP, btw. That is, to the closest larger integer. `floor` rounds down.

Comment: I believe they worked the same way. I tried both `round` and `ceil` before.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round 
"Computes the nearest integer value to arg (in floating-point format), rounding halfway cases away from zero, regardless of the current rounding mode."

There's `floor` which should do the trick.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan did you try them on both of your examples?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes. I tried it using this way `(ceil(1 + 3 + 6)/3)` but it seems to still round my number down instead of up.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan why all the extra math. Test both functions with plain numbers to see the different behavior.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan While you are at it, try `floor()`, too.

Answer (score 6):

`std::round` may be the one you're looking for. However, bear in mind that it returns a float. You may want to try `lround` or `llround` to get a result in long or long long (C++ 11).

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round

Answer (score 1):

In c++, by including cmath library we can use use various functions which rounds off the value both up or down.

```
std::trunc
```

This simply truncates the decimal part, thas is, the digits after the decimal point no matter what the decimal is.

```
std::ceil
```

This is used to round up to the closest integer value.

```
std::floor
```

This is used to round down to the closest integer value.

```
std::round
```

This will round to the nearest integer value whichever is the closest, that is, it can be round up or round down.

Comment: The other answer already mentions those functions (except `trunc`, which OP wasn't asking about). This answer doesn't seem to add any new information...

Answer (score 0):

When using ceil, make sure that the argument you pass in it is of float data type. For example if you want to round up (16/6) to 3 then use :
ceil(16/6.0);

Hope it helps...