# In C++, how do I round numbers without displaying them using only iostream, and iomanip?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

For example, I want 2.22 to round to 2 and 7.8 to round up to 8, and I want to use these values as integers later in my code to print out a certain number of asterisks.  Turning them into int values rounds them down automatically, but I need a number to round up, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: why do you do `cout << ...` if you want to round without displaying? google: "c++ rounding"

Comment: Streams. There is not only `cin` and `cout`.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round

Comment: `cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setprecision(0) << b << endl << c << endl;` does not do any rounding of the variables.  It just displays them as rounded.  If you need them rounded then you need to get a `round` function.

Comment: are you looking for a string stream?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925020/rounding-up-and-down-a-number-c/39925071#39925071

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `round()` function, such as the one below, which works for positive numbers.

```
double round(double d)
{
  return floor(d + 0.5);
}
```

You need the [`floor()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/floor/) function for this, found in `<cmath>`. I honestly cannot think of anything involving JUST `<iostream>` and `<iomanip>`

EDIT: For another approach, use [`std::round()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round), from `<cmath>`

Comment: I mentioned it @SergeRogatch

Comment: Rounding is much more complex than that. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking . So your function covers too little of the possibilities,