# C++ compound assignment and type conversion issue

Tags: c++

I am calculating combination(15, 7) in C++.

1. I first used the following code and get the wrong answer due to a [type promotion error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663545/does-one-double-promote-every-int-in-the-equation-to-double).

   ```
   #include <iostream>

   int main()
   {
       int a = 15;
       double ans = 1;
       for(int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
           ans *= (a + 1 - i) / i;
       std::cout << (int) ans;

       return 0;
   }
   ```

   **Output:** `2520`
2. So I changed `ans *= (a + 1 - i) / i;` to `ans *= (double)(a + 1 - i) / i;` and still get the wrong answer.

   ```
   #include <iostream>

   int main()
   {
       int a = 15;
       double ans = 1;
       for(int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
           ans *= (double) (a + 1 - i) / i;
       std::cout << (int) ans;

       return 0;
   }
   ```

   **Output:** `6434`
3. Finally, I tried `ans = ans * (a + 1 - i) / i`, which gives the right answer.

   ```
   #include <iostream>

   int main()
   {
       int a = 15;
       double ans = 1;
       for(int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
           ans = ans * (a + 1 - i) / i;
       std::cout << (int) ans;

       return 0;
   }
   ```

   **Output:** `6435`

Could someone tell me why the second one did not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you print out `ans` without casting it to `(int)` you'll see the second result is `6434.9999999999990905052982270717620849609375`. That's pretty darn close to the right answer of `6535`, so it's clearly not a type promotion error any more.

No, this is classic [floating point inaccuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate). When you write `ans *= (double) (a + 1 - i) / i` you are doing the equivalent of:

```
ans = ans * ((double) (a + 1 - i) / i);
```

Compare this to the third version:

```
ans = ans * (a + 1 - i) / i;
```

The former performs division first followed by multiplication. The latter operates left to right and so the multiplication precedes the division. This change in order of operations causes the results of the two to be slightly different. Floating point calculations are extremely sensitive to order of operations.

**Quick fix:** Don't *truncate* the result; [round](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925020/rounding-up-and-down-a-number-c) it.

**Better fix:** Don't use floating point for integral arithmetic. Save the divisions until after all the multiplications are done. Use `long`, `long long`, or even a [big number library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988099/big-numbers-library-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

First one did not work because you have integer division there.

Difference btw second one and third one is this:

```
ans = ans * (double(a + 1 - i) / i); // second is equal to this
```

vs:

```
ans = (ans * (a + 1 - i)) / i; // third is equal to this
```

so difference is in order of multiplication and division. If you round double to integer instead of simply dropping fractional part you will get the same result.

```
std::cout << int( ans + 0.5 ) << std::endl;
```

Comment: My only thing is that after I commented that, I realized the result is only a difference between 2. and 3. of 1. I wouldn't think that that type of error would only be off by 1 when used in a multiplication like that.

Comment: It is not off by 1, it is off by 0.000000001, but because you dropping fractional part you do not see that.

Comment: Okay, I get that part. With the carry over, and truncation, etc. I know it looks like it's off by 1, but not really. But what I'm saying is shouldn't the difference be larger than 1, not less?